# Get the last sign in date and time for all users from Firebase Auth using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app where I use Firebase Auth, and also I use Firestore to store the users data.
And I want to be able to get the user last Signed In date and time as shown in the image bellow.

[image]

Note that this info is for the admin only.

Thank you in advance!

I tried using the auth.currentUser!.metadata.lastSignInTime
It worked but I want to display this info for all users listed, and for the view of the admin only.

Comment: Try adding firebase admin SDK to get all the users form firebase. 
Note: But its not available for mobile enviironments. For more please check this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users